# Exclude caption from listing margin in IEEEtran v1.8a

Tags: listings, ieeetran

I have the following setup for the *listings* package, including a left margin to have the line numbers stay within the column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{
language=Python,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=2em,
frame=single,
captionpos=b,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
breaklines=true,
tabsize=3,
numberbychapter=false,
keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={This could be a very long description. In real life, my document is in two-column so I have even less space for the listing caption.}]
def foo():
    bar()
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This works fine for the *article* class. However, I have to work with the IEEE Transactions class v1.8 (for example here: http://cruise.eecs.uottawa.ca/models2015/resources/IEEEtran.cls) but as soon as I replace the document class article with *IEEEtran* in the above example, I get a listing caption that exceeds the column width.

[image]

Comment: did you check the *caption* package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `\@makecaption` of class `IEEEtran` does not have an explicit `\par` at the end. TeX evaluates the paragraph parameters at the end of the paragraph. The `\par` comes later *after* `\@makecaption` with the setting of option `xleftmargin` in force.

The following example adds an explicit `\par` at the end of `\@makecaption`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\@makecaption{\par}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\@makecaption could not be patched}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  numbers=left,   
  xleftmargin=2em,
  frame=single,   
  captionpos=b,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=3,
  numberbychapter=false,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={This could be a very long description. In real
life, my document is in two-column so I have even less space for the listing
caption.}]
def foo():
    bar() 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. Will award the bounty as soon as this is possible